# Two reason why zipcode should be stored as a string data type

Tags: c++

In the textbook "Starting Out In C++" by Gaddis in chapter 1 the author says that some numbers like zip codes are intended for humans to read, to be printed out on the screen to look at and to not calculate with so they should be stored in string data type not numeric data types.  But there is a couple of other reasons why this statement is true.  The only other reason why I can think this would be true is if you were to enter a zip code with an ending like 37217-1221 you may have to use string catenation to only use the first five digits chopping of the characters after the -1221.  What would be some other reasons for the statement "If a number is not going to be used in an arithmetic operation, store it in a string data type".  Any answers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: International postal codes

Comment: A ZIP code isn't strictly a number; it's an identifier.

Answer (score 1):

Zipcodes simply are not numeric data. As you point out, zipcodes can contain extensions, which numeric data does not represent. They can also contain significant leading zeros. Some postal code schemes can also contain letters.

Comment: Yup, good luck mailing to [our neighbors to the north](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postal_codes_in_Canada) if you don't allow alphabetics.

Comment: @MarkRansom You neighbor of north is here. What are you going to mail me?

Answer (score 0):

Your questions was a bit...not of a questions? That's the best I can explain it. Anyway, a string is text and an integer or number is numerical and should only be used for calculations or counting. For example:

A zip code is a number but you will never do calculations with it. A zip code is something you reference as a place and has no counting purpose. If you think this could confuse you later on try to give the variable with the zip code an assignment of a String so that you cannot try to do any sort of math with the variable.